# How to remove an element and append python list conditionally?

Tags: python, list

I receive timeseries data from a broker and want to implement condition monitoring on this data. I want to analyze the data in a window of size 10. The window size must always stay the same. When the 11th data comes, I need to check its value against two thresholds which are calculated from the 10 values inside a window. If the 11th data is outsider, I must delete the data from the list and if it is within the range, I must delete the first element and add the 11th data to the last element. So this way the size of window stays the same. The code is simplified. `data` comes each 1 second.

```
temp_list = []
window_size = 10

if len(temy_list) <= window_size :
    temp_list.append(data)
if len(temp_list) == 10:
    avg = statistics.mean(temp_list)
    std = statistics.stdev(temp_list)
    u_thresh = avg + 3*std
    l_thresh = avg - 3*std
    temp_list.append(data)
    if temp_list[window_size] < l_thresh or temp_list[window_size] > u_thresh:
        temp_list.pop(-1)

    else:
        temp_list.pop(0)
        temp_list.append(data)
```

With this code the list does not get updated and 11th data is stored and then no new data. I don't know how to correctly implement it. Sorry, if it is a simple question. I am still not very comfortable with python list. Thank you for your hint/help.

Comment: That last line is unneeded, since you've already appended `data` to the list.  It pushes the list length to 11, so the `len() == 10` check never passes again.

Comment: I deleted the last line. For the first new data, it got updated and after that with the new data no updates.

Comment: can you please give a sample of how the values from 'data' looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With how your code currently is if you plan to keep the last data point you add it twice instead. You can simplify your code down to make it a bit more clear and straightforward.

```
##First setup your initial variables
temp_list = []
window_size = 10
```

Then -

```
While(True):
    data = ##Generate/Get data here

    ## If less than 10 data points add them to list
    if len(temp_list) < window_size :
        temp_list.append(data)
    ## If already at 10 check if its within needed range
    else:
        avg = statistics.mean(temp_list)
        std = statistics.stdev(temp_list)
        u_thresh = avg + 3*std
        l_thresh = avg - 3*std
        ## If within range add point to end of list and remove first element
        if(data >= l_thresh and data <= u_thresh):
            temp_list.pop(0)
            temp_list.append(data)
```

Comment: while didn't work for me but the logic works. Thanks.